# The parameter '***' was not bound in the specified LINQ to Entities query expression

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expression, expression-trees

I am doing a common query in my project. I use Expression to build my query tree, the code list below:

```
 public IList<Book> GetBooksFields(string fieldName, string fieldValue)
    {
        ParameterExpression paramLeft = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "m." + fieldName);
        ParameterExpression paramRight = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "\"" + fieldValue + "\"");

        ParameterExpression binaryLeft = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Book),"m");
        BinaryExpression binaryExpr = Expression.Equal(paramLeft, paramRight);

        var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<Book, bool>>(binaryExpr, binaryLeft);

        return bookRepository.GetMany(expr).ToList();

    }
```

But when I invoke my `GetBooksFields` method, it will throw me an exception as below:
[image]

I debugged the expr variable and got the correct expression: {`m => (m.Name == "sdf")`}, it was what I want, But I don't know why I got the error,thx.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't "trick" LINQ into interpreting parameters as member-expressions by throwing in dots into variable names.

You'll have to construct the expression-tree correctly, as below
(EDIT: changed field to property as per your comment):

```
public IList<Book> GetBooksFields(string propertyName, string propertyValue)
{
     var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Book), "book");

     var left = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);   

     var convertedValue = Convert.ChangeType
                          ( 
                              propertyValue, 
                              typeof(Book).GetProperty(propertyName).PropertyType
                          );

     var right = Expression.Constant(convertedValue);

     var binaryExpr = Expression.Equal(left, right);        
     var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<Book, bool>>(binaryExpr, parameter);     

     return bookRepository.GetMany(expr).ToList();          
}
```

Comment: thanks. But I tried your approach and got error at row : Expression.Field(parameter, fieldName), the exception is : Didn't define field "Name" for type "TinyFrame.Data.DomainModel.Book". Any ideas? I can see in my BookDomainmodel, there are "Name" field.

Comment: Is it a field or a property? Show us your Book class.

Comment: sry for my mistake, it's a property:
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public string Publishment { get; set; }
        public int BookTypeID { get; set; }
        public int BookPlaceID { get; set; }

        public virtual BookType BookType { get; set; }
        public virtual BookPlace BookPlace { get; set; }

Comment: I modified all the field to property , and now it works fine.

Comment: @Ani You also could've used `Expression.PropertyOrField()`.

Comment: @svick: I could have, yes. But note I'm also getting the member through  typeof(Book).GetProperty(propertyName).PropertyType, which is harder to generalize across fields / properties. Although I suppose left.ExpressionType would have worked and been easier...

Comment: @Ani If i want to do query the property in nested entities, What should I do now? ie, I want to query the property "Position" in BookPlace entity, which exists in Book entity?

Comment: @Ani I used the System.Linq.Dynamic lib , all my questions are now solved, thx for your help .