# Runtime joins to query within Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, expression-trees

I have a database that is mapped using the Entity Framework. Entity Framework is generating the C# code of the database objects in the similar manner as shown below. For simplicity I have created `Parent`, `Child`, `GrandChild` hierarchy but the actual db contains much longer hierarchies and many other fields.

```
class Parent
{
  string name;
  int id;
  datetime DateOfBirth;
}

class Child
{
    string name;
    int id;
    int ParentId; ( FK reference to Parent Child )
}

class GrandChild
{
    string name;
    int id;
    int ChildId; (FK reference to Child )
}
```

Now, I am building an api where the filters will be provided at runtime. I mean, some of the queries could be

1. Give all GrandChild rows for ParentId =1
2. Give All Grandchild rows for ChildName = "x"
3. Give all GrandChild rows for Parent with DateOfbirth = "x/y/z"

So, how can I build in C# code, using LINQ or Expression Trees to create predicates and join filters dynamically/runtime.

Following URL:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb882637.aspx

shows how to create dynamic query, but not how to INNER JOIN multiple such queries. Does anyone know how to do that?

This Stackoverflow answer:
[The parameter '***' was not bound in the specified LINQ to Entities query expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23003552/the-parameter-was-not-bound-in-the-specified-linq-to-entities-query-expres)

also highlights how to create filters dynamically but not how to join them.

Does anyone know how to create dynamic queries to filter rows and join the queries? Let me know if you need more information. Thanks

Comment: With EF, you may not need Joins, the conceptual model would have navigation properties, which can be directly accessed.  https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/

Comment: Do your real models also have `id` & `name` values? Or is this just an example and your real models all have different properties etc and a lot of properties?

Comment: @Agalo Thanks for the link. Any idea how to dynamically create such navigation linq queries.

Comment: @AlexanderDerck The real models have id, name plus many other properties that the callers may want to filter by

Comment: If the properties of the models are consistent, you can write some generic extension methods with interface constraint, but if the models all have random properties etc. that's not really doable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm going to suppose that is not your real model because you should have properties instead fields and your entities must be `public`.

If you have represented your db relationships using [navigation properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx), you could create a [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) like this:

```
static IQueryable<TEntity> Select<TEntity>(this  IQueryable<TEntity> query, List<Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>> filters = null,
                                           List<Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>> includes = null)
{
   if (includes != null)
   {
      query = includes.Aggregate(query, (current, include) => current.Include(include));
   }
   if (filters != null)
   {
      query = filters.Aggregate(query, (current, filter) => current.Where(filter)); //at the end this is going to be translated to condition1 && condition2 ...
   }
   return query;
}
```

In the first list you pass all the conditions you want to apply to your query and the second helps you to load the related entities that you need in your query:

```
var conditions = new List<Expression<Func<GrandChild, bool>>>() { (t) => t.Child.Parent.ParentId==1 };
var includes = new List<Expression<Func<GrandChild, object>>>() { (t) => t.Child.Parent };

var query= yourContext.GrandChilds.Select(filters,includes);
```

Comment: I think what OP might be asking is how to build the `var conditions` dynamically. AFAIK, this isn't supported in EF6, but I thought EF7 might have talked about doing it.

Answer (score 0):

1 . Give all GrandChild rows for ParentId =1

```
 var grandChildData=from grand in GrandChild
                    join ch in Child on grand.ChildId equals ch.Id
                    where ch.ParentId==1
                    select grand;
```

Answer (score 0):

2. Give All Grandchild rows for ChildName = "x"

   ```
    var grandChildData=from grand in GrandChild
                  join ch in Child on grand.ChildId equals ch.Id
                  where ch.name = "x"
                  select grand;
   ```
3. Give all GrandChild rows for Parent with DateOfbirth = "x/y/z"

   ```
    var grandChildData=from grand in GrandChild
                      join ch in Child on grand.ChildId equals ch.Id
                      join p in Parent on ch.ParentId equals p.id
                      where p.DateOfbirth==Convert.ToDateTime("2016/01/01")
                      select grand;
   ```